# ASP.net c# Error, CS1061: 'Web2Print.ArtworkLabel' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, class

The error I am getting is:

> CS1061: 'Web2Print.ArtworkLabel' does
>   not contain a definition for 'ID' and
>   no extension method 'ID' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'Web2Print.ArtworkLabel' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

On the line:

```
string FormVal = Request.Form["label" + TheLabel.ID];
```

The code block the line is in is:

```
public void SaveData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // New data record
    ArtworkData DataRecord = new ArtworkData(DataID);
    DataRecord.LoadTemplate();
    DataRecord.Template.LoadLabels();
    DataRecord.LoadDataLabels();

    // Delete all from DB
    ArtworkCommon.DeleteDataLabels(DataID);

    ArrayList LabelsCollection = new ArrayList();

    // Loop through all the fields
    foreach (ArtworkLabel TheLabel in DataRecord.Template.Labels)
    {
        string FormVal = Request.Form["label" + TheLabel.ID];
```

The definition of `ArtworkLabel` is:

```
/// <summary>
/// A template label
/// </summary>
public class ArtworkLabel
{
    public bool Loaded { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public LabelStyle Style { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coords { get; set; }
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
```

The code isn't very well formed, I know.  The function throwing the error exists in namespace `Web2Print`, but the `ArtworkLabel` class does not exist in a namespace.  I don't think this should be a problem.

I've tried rebuilding, clearing temp files as well.

Comment: Is it gagging on the fact that ID is an int that you're using in a string?

Comment: @DOK No I've tried putting `ToString()` but it throws the same error.

Comment: If you debug what kind of properties does the `TheLabel` have? Do me, it feels like your referencing an old dll or somethink, that does not have the `ID` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function throwing the error exists
>   in namespace Web2Print, but the
>   ArtworkLabel class does not exist in a
>   namespace

Everything must be in a namespace.  Figure out what namespace ArtworkLabel is in, and refer to it as `ArtworkLabelNameSpace.ArtworkLabel`.

Also check if there's a control called `ArtworkLabel` in your ASPX file; the error message sounds like it actually finds a matching object, but the object doesn't define an ID property.

Comment: There is no conflicting controls.  Does everything have to be in a namespace?  It's in a .CS file as a public class.  Putting it in a namespace will be a bit of a pain but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: I suppose if you don't specify a namespace explicitly, the class ends up in the default namespace for the project.  You can use a tool like [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP) to inspect your assembly, if you can get it in a state where it compiles.